# How to serialize and deserialise list of objects in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, stream

I have a `List<Animal>` that i want to send as a SOAP response to the client but the send method requires `byte[]` and deserialize in the client.

Can anyone tell me how to convert my `List<Animal>` to `byte[]` and convert the `byte[]` back to the `List<Animal>`.

I know there is lots of questions like this in this site, but I am confuse with the answers. I tried a lot of them but none of the worked for me.

Comment: I tried that. It only works for a single object or objects, but not foe nested objects like List<Animal>

Comment: Again I tried the code you suggested. It throws java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.util.List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static byte[] objectToByteArray(Object obj) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    oos.close();
    return bytes;
}

public static Object byteArrayToObject(byte[] buffer) throws Exception {
    Object ob = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
            buffer));
    ob = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return ob;
}
```

Comment: You have to explain about your code for better understanding.

Comment: `baos.close()` is redundant here.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on Animal. If it is Serializable you can use Java Serialization mechanizm https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html.